# ASP.Net: How to store a collection and keep different values for different tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate, static-members

I my UserControl I am storing a small collection in a object like this

```
static ListThingCollection _mylistThingColl = new ListThingCollection ();
public ListThingCollection myListThingColl
{
    get { return _mylistThingColl ; }
    set { _mylistThingColl = value; }
}
```

This collection is used to populate some fields.

Since it is a static object, if I use my website in two different web browser tabs at same time, the content of this object on the first tab may be updated to the content of the second tab.

What can I use to skip this situation?

I tried with ViewState, but since this collection is at my UserControl, when the code returns to the .aspx page, for some reason, it throws a post back and my page gets reloaded to the initial state, with blank fields. I also tried with Session, but the problem with different tabs was the same as aspected.

Comment: You should definitely avoid static objects.  Is there something wrong with getting your data from the database with every request?  Otherwise, you can look into putting it in the session or use some caching mechanism.

Comment: @RobinNadeau, but if I put it in a Session, when I use the same webpage in two different tabs, one session will be updated by the other (the session is unique and the same for all tabs =(, that is my problem), so the colection of the first tab will be the same as the collection of the second tab.

Comment: I assume that when you put in your ViewState, it ends up being too big and ends up throwing?  If that's the case, I once solved that problem by storing a random key in the viewstate, and then storing the information in some cache using that random key.  If you're interested in this sort of solution, let me know and I can whip you up some sample code.

Comment: @RobinNadeau the Collection has only from 1 to 10 small data. The problem is that whenever I reach the viewstate that is inside a UserControl , when the code comes back to the main page, the viewstate change to nul ( think that its is expected) and in the end the page gets reloaded (this is not expected =/ )

Comment: In which event are you looking in the viewstate?  Because the viewstate is not available on init.  Check in the page load if your viewstate is filled in.